# Mysql Relation DB for mailer

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create a DB for a  PHP Mailer App, The program will allow user to Login, Once user logs into the system they will be able to write Send to: email, Subject, from and select HTML template form drop down menu. I have an gd understanding of how to accomplish these but because I am not so good with designing a Database I decided to ask for help here.

So I have identyfied 3 tables :

```
Users[id, firstname, lastname, email, password] 
Message[id, send_to, subject, template_used, from, date, ip_address] 
Template[id, temp_name, temp_html].
```

I am struggling with the relational database concepts but this is how I see it:

User 1..* -----------1..* Message, Message 1..1 ----------- 1..1 Template, 
Template 1..1--------1..* Users

Not to sure about these relation and if the relation between User and Message is correct is it this a problem where two tables are 1..*.....?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? - it should be  `User 1..* ----- 1..1 Message, Message 1..1 ------- *..1 Template, Template *..* Users`

Answer (score 0):

A good database in relational model requires the tables at least to conform up to the third normalization rule (3N).Please read something  about 1N 2N 3N.For now, that is, the existing relationships should be reduced to (one to many). There cannot be many to many if you expect a wonderful RD.
Lets analyse the relationship of user to messages tables:
Situation 1: 
One user  can have many messages,i.e (user ----messages) ----(one to many)
One message  can be for many users, I.e (message -----users)-----one to many
This implies messages to users has many to many relationships. By normalization rules, this is not correct (For the sake of referential integrity).
This can be avoided by introducing another table that would act as intermediary , call it (messageuser). This table will contain the primary key of messages foreign key and user foreign key as it primary key thus composite key.
What therefore do we notice:

(Figure: simple illustration-not standard)-sorry i could not upload the picture to show you that as guided by the site's rules and policies.

We now have three tables with two relationships with each one in the form of (one to many).
i.e user to usermessage (one user has one message with his id) and message to user(one message is send to one user with particular id).
Is that not great.